# Can you update a single document based on the current state consistently?

Tags: mongodb

Imagine I have a document structure like this.

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('internalId'),
    externalId: 'externalId',
    history: [
        {
            effective: ISODate('2000-02-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
            property: 'new value'
        },
        {
            effective: ISODate('2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
            property: 'value'
        }
    ]
}
```

Each time this document is read, all of the properties are merged together in historical order into a final state, possibly stopping at a specific point in time.

To add a new history item, I would need to perform something like this.

```
{
    $push: {
        history: {
            property: 'even newer value',
            effective: new Date()
        }
    },
    $setOnInsert: {
        externalId: externalId
    }
}
```

I would like to find a way to make sure that an update that does not modify the actual merged history state is never stored. However it seems like this would require a separate read operation, and thus an (external) pessimistic lock to be held, while it was determined if a revision could proceed.

This feels like an incorrect design. Help!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I get it as "all of the properties are merged together" stuff happens on clientside, so it must be responsibility of the client to decide whether to add new history item or not.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is possible, but requires a pessimistic locking mechanism to be designed. This is a possible solution. I am looking for alternative solutions to consider.

Comment: I doubt conditional push with upserts is possible. Especially having abstract "*final state, possibly stopping at a specific point in time.*" condition.